# Are there any materials which are transparent only to some wavelengths of visible light?

Tags: visible-light

So glass allows visible light through, but blocks UV light. Are there any materials which only allow certain wavelengths of visible light through? If so, what are the uses of this?

Comment: There are all kinds of optical filters available for all kinds of uses. This is really broad.

Comment: @JonCuster is it broad, though? I hadn't heard of these optical filters, and I still don't know anything about them. I asked for an example of such a material.

Comment: For any number of optical systems there are catalogs full of filters. Photography as well. Stained glass windows. Etc.

Comment: Any transparent colorful thing does that, no idea how one can know glass blocks UV and don't know colorful glass absorbs also some visible.

Answer (score 2):

You know a blue filter or a red filter for a camera, that filters out all but one color, reds or blues.

Comment: Ah, I feel stupid now, I completely forgot about these, even though I use them. My only excuse is that it was past midnight and I was tired.

Comment: @JacobGarby it’s okay everyone has that moment and some people don’t know that’s how filters work so somebody is bound to learn something lol

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main types, absorption filters and dichroic filters.  Absorption filters use a dye mixed into the glass that say for example absorbed blue and green so everything looks red when you look thru it.  Any cheap sunglasses may show the effect, but there are expensive filters as well, ex photography.  Dichroic filters are a little pricier, they are wavelength thin layers that block the light due to the wave properties of certain wavelengths  of light, found in expensive sun glasses, science labs, military equipment etc.